# Print Array as comma separated list in a .each block

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

If i have this simple block

```
<% p.sectors.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.name %>
<% end %>
```

That iterates through all of the sectors , how would i get the results to print out in a comma separated sentence, so something like this

```
web design, web development, Software testing
```

There is a method called to_sentence but is that relevant here and how do i apply this method?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you may use <%= p.sectors.map(&:to_sentence).join(', ') %>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= p.sectors.map(&:name).join(", ") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= p.sectors.map{|item| item.name}.join(',')%>
```